# Show full Div with change background color of whole div using Hover CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to hover image or text in a `div`, and want to change the `background-color` of the whole `div` including the inner `div` of the hovering element.

Here is the code:

```css
.hover-div {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #186459;
  color: white;
}

.hover-object:hover+.hover-div {
  background-color: #666666;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="touch">
  <div className="hover-object">
    <img src={dashboardkpi} className="svg-image" alt='img' />
    <p className="item-names">Dashboard KPI</p>
  </div>
  <p className="hover-div">View business analytics</p>
</div>
```

I want to Hover `class="hover-object"` and change the background color of whole `div` named 'touch' to blue and display `class="hover-div"` content.

Till now, when i hover , only `hover-div` appears with change background color. I wish when i hover, the hover content display and the whole div 'touch' background color change.

Comment: If you want to traverse back up the DOM from a child element to parent, this is unfortunately not possible with CSS. You can only traverse from parent > child and not child > parent. You could resort to JavaScript OR change your html structure (recommended) so you can keep it CSS 'only', like the suggestion of Chanond Wongpiya below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `.touch:hover` in your CSS.